# Add Dynamic field to bootstrap multiple select dropdown list

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to add fields dynamically to multiple select dropdownlist. 
Here is what i have tried

```
$('.applicationNameSelectClass').multiselect({
         numberDisplayed: 1,
        enableFiltering: true
});

function addField(){
    var val =document.getElementById("addField").value;
    $('#selectList').append('<option>'+val+'</option>');
}

<body>
Dynamically Add DropDown Field...<BR><BR>
<input type="text" id="addField"/>

<input type="button" id="theButton" value="AddField!" onclick="addField();">
<select id="selectList" name="applicationNames" class="applicationNameSelectClass" multiple="multiple" style="width: 147px; " >
    <option><c:out value="Option-1"/></option>
    <option><c:out value="Option-2"/></option>
    <option><c:out value="Option-3"/></option>
    <option><c:out value="Option-4"/></option>
    </select>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the onclick bind is not working for you inside the input element: `onclick="addField();"` Not sure why, but might be the order you're loading your page. I suggest you to use this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/jotamartins/rr2vorb2/) for binding click event:

```
$('#theButton').click(function() {
    var val = document.getElementById("addField").value;
    $('#selectList').append('<option>'+val+'</option>');
});
```

Remember to put it inside an ondomready context, like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jotamartins/rr2vorb2/)

Comment: Thanks @jmartins for helping me out but still its not working...i have updated question with screen shot

Comment: Why not? It is working on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jotamartins/rr2vorb2/). The only difference is that I didn't put bootstrap on it

Comment: without applying bootstrap plugin it works, but once you apply bootstrap plugin to dropdown list it's not working